# Can my wife travel alone to France on EU settlement family permit?

Tags: visas, europe, eurostar, bangladeshi-citizens

I’m a citizen of France living in the UK, and my wife is planning to travel to France from the UK to visit. She is a Bangladeshi citizen and has an 'EU settlement scheme family permit' visa. Is she able to travel to France with me without any further visas?

Permit expires 27 July 2021. She will be fingerprinted for BMC on 26th April 2021 and is planning to travel afterwards.

Comment: "UK EU settlement scheme family permit" is unclear: what is the actual name of the permit she has, when was the permit issued, and which country issued it? If she does not yet have the permit, from which government will the permit be obtained and what is the permit named? What is her citizenship? Where does she live?

Comment: The name of permit EU settlement scheme family permit

Comment: She’s citizen of Bangladeshi and got visa embassy of uk Bangladesh

Comment: What was the date the permit was issued?

Comment: Date of permit issued is 27 January 2021 and date of expire 27 July 2021

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: the EU Settlement Scheme family permit is unambiguous: it is a document issued by the UK to family members of those participating in the EU Settlement Scheme, which is the program under the Immigration Rules that preserves the rights of people who established themselves in the UK under the Immigration (EEA) Regulations 2016 before December 31, 2020.  See https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eu-settlement-scheme-family-permit.

Comment: @GrahamNye is there any indication that she is in Bangladesh?  She could be traveling to France from the UK.  Josim: where is she now?

Comment: @GrahamNye my wife now in the uk with me and I need travel to france with my wife it’s possible?

Comment: @phoog Good point. I misread the question. As OP has clarified their wife is currently in the UK I've deleted my irrelevant comment about red lists. josim will still need to check France's COVID rules on travel from the UK.

Answer (score 5):

The question appears to be about visas rather than COVID-19 travel restrictions.  Your wife needs a separate visa to enter France.

Before the UK left the EU, she would have been able to travel to France using a "residence card of a family member of a union citizen."  But the EEA family permit (the document that was analogous to the EU Settlement Scheme family permit) did not confer an exemption from the visa requirement.  Furthermore, the residence permit that she will eventually receive under the EUSS will not entitle her to enter the Schengen area without a visa, because the UK is no longer a member of the EU.

As others have noted, you should also pay close attention to COVID-19 travel restrictions, both those imposed by France and those imposed by the UK.